# How to fill area between two line serie in tradingview api javascript

Tags: charts, fill, area, tradingview-api, lineseries

Hello I have been searching through the documentation and I didn't find any way to fill the area between two line series with a color I'm looking for something like the image below:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this feature is not available yet and there is a request for this feature on their GitHub :
https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/140